# Boolean not right value in admin page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have django 2.2.8 and in my model I use boolean value

```
legacy = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Responsable')
```

but when I open my admin page I display the wrong value (the opposite value).

In my `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        ('General',
            {
                'classes': ('collapse',),
                'fields': (
                    'legacy',
    ...
```

In my DB the value is right but in the admin page I have the `checkbox` checked instead of not (for instance)

And I have other `BooleanField` in the same `Model` with the right value !!

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you register your model in the admin? Are you using the _default_ `ModelAdmin`? Please include your `admin.py` file

Comment: Done, I specify that all works well instead of my BooleanField